# Flag emoji causing differing widths in Flutter

Tags: flutter, layout, emoji

Some flag emoji seem to have extra padding. See the image below:

[image]

You can see the Danish flag is taking double width, but the British flag has the correct width.

Here is the complete project code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

void main() {
  debugPaintSizeEnabled = true;
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('My App')),
        body: BodyWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BodyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 100,
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(50),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text('', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),),
          Text('', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong? I want all of the flags to have the same width.

It is making alignment problems for me in a bigger project.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appear to be a bug rather than a programming problem. Make sure you have upgraded to the latest version of Flutter. As of Flutter 1.12.13+hotfix.6 • channel beta I am no longer seeing this issue.

Related GitHub issues:

- https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/43230
- https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/41792